# How do i add linting to pre-commit hook

Tags: git, bash, githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

hi everyone i have a git repo that house 3 folders (individual js projects).

here's my `pre-commit` hook

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\033[1;92m Linting Staged Files . . . "

files=$(git diff --diff-filter=d --cached --name-only | grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$')
path=(${files[0]//// })


if [[ $files = "" ]] ; then
  echo -e "\033[1;31m You have no staged file, exiting . . "
  exit 1
fi

for file in $files
do
git show ":$file" | $("./$path/node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename $file")
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo -e "\033[1;31m ESLint failed on staged file '$file'. \n Code will not be committed, Please fix your code and try again."
exit 1
 fi
done

BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

if [[ "$BRANCH" == "master" || "$BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
 echo "\033[1;31m commiting to $BRANCH is illegal."
 echo "\033[1;31m If you really know what you're doing, then add the argument '-n' to skip this git hook."
 exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

but it keeps failing at this line `git show ":$file" | $("./$path/node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename $file")`

with an error

`.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 17: ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename sfa/src/SFAApp.js: No such file or directory`

i have no idea what i'm doing wrong please help.

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind i fixed the problem by changing

`$("./$path/node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename $file")`

to

`./$path/node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename $file`

TODO: research what `$()` really means in bash.

Comment: In short: Executing a subscript within your script

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run a command literally named:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename sfa/src/SFAApp.js
```

rather than trying to run a command named:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint
```

with arguments:

```
--stdin
```

and:

```
--stdin-filename
```

and:

```
sfa/src/SFAApp.js
```

The cure is to fix your double quote placement.  Once you do, you will probably have a second problem:

```
git show ":$file" | $(./$path/node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename "$file")
```

will run the command with the arguments, but then, because it is inside `$(...)`, will take its output as a command.  I know nothing of eslint, but it seems likely that this should read:

```
git show ":$file" | ./$path/node_modules/.bin/eslint --stdin --stdin-filename "$file"
```

(I'm also not at all sure what the silliness with `$path` is about.  The line `path=(${files[0]//// })` sets `path` to the first file path-name component of the files listed by `git diff`, e.g., if the output is `a/b/c.js`, `path` is set to `a`.)

Comment: like i said the git repo has doesn't hold an actual project but other folders with different projects in them, therefore i have to get the folder name of the files modified and execute the eslint of **that** folder, with the configs of that folder.

Comment: Aha. Well, that's not going to work if there are changes or new files in `a/dir1/file1.js` *and* `b/dir2/file2.js`.  You'd need to pick out the right path *per file* (or perhaps forbid a commit that affects multiple sub-projects).

Comment: I probably need to get the folder path per file instead of just getting the first one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the npm package **husky** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky

By tapping into the git hook for pre-commit you could lint all the staged files exculding the deleted one by the line below

> git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=d | grep ".js$" | xargs ./node_modules/.bin/eslint

Your .huskyrc will pretty much look like the one below:

```
module.exports = {
 'hooks': {
   'pre-commit': 'git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=d | grep ".js$" | xargs ./node_modules/.bin/eslint'
  }
}
```